# Perform some action on particular item from List in Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Problem I am facing that I can't delete any row or multiple row from list when I click on delete button.Here is my code:

```
    {
        xtype: 'list',
        store: "Plays",
        itemId:"playsList",
        mode: 'MULTI',
        loadingText: "Loading PlaysList...",
        emptyText: '<div class="notes-list-empty-text">No PlayList found.</div>',
        itemTpl: '<div class="list"><div class="list-item-title">{title}</div><div class="list-item-narrative">{duration}</div><div class="list-item-hide">{hidden}</div></div>',      
        itemSelector: 'div.list',

   },
    {
                    xtype: "button",
                    iconCls: "trash",
                    iconMask: true,
                    itemId: "deleteButton"
            },

   onDeleteButtonTap: function () {
        //console.log("deleteNoteCommand");//How to get value of recored from playlist

    this.fireEvent("deleteNoteCommand", this);
},
```

Now I select any row and click on delete button then how can I get the value of selected item or row and perform some action by tapping button.
Like here I am perfroming deletion of selected rows
Controller

```
  Ext.define("PlayListApp.controller.Plays", {
      extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
         refs: {
        // We're going to lookup our views by xtype.
        notesListView: "playslistview",
         notesList: "#playsList",
  },
  },
   onDeleteNoteCommand: function () {
      console.log("onDeleteNoteCommand");

    var noteEditor = this.getNotesList();
    console.log(noteEditor);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you tap on button after select on record of list you can get that selected record of list using below code

```
  var record= this.getNotesList().getSelection()[0];
```

this code gives you selected record and after that you can remove record from store using below code

```
this.getNotesList().getStore().remove(record);//bracket in here too....
```

Comment: I got error when I console record Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
            args.push.apply(args, arguments);
            return fn.apply(scope || this, args);
        } has no method 'getSelection'

Comment: sorry add () brecket at end of this.getNotesList

Comment: I also didn't see bracket...Sorry for that :)

Comment: One question more How to delete mutiple row means I want to add in array.

Comment: getSelection() gives you array so you can loop throw this array and one by one pass into remove() method as perameter that's it.

Comment: How can I perform inline editing when I click on button you get inline textfield.How can i do it as there is not option as such?